# What is this SQL query doing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I wish there was a more general language question here, but the whole query feels specifically confusing. :P I've never seen one SQL statement followed by a comma (rather than semicolon), followed by what looks like *not* another statement, nor what looks like a subquery with additional WHERE clauses after it. So...wtf?

When I run this query, I get a single result set containing two columns: `Address` and `Zip`.

This is running against SQL Server btw.

```sql
    SELECT 
        [Address] AS [Address],
        [AgencySitesV3].[Zip] AS [Zip]
    FROM
        [AgencySitesV3] WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [Zip] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [AgencySitesV3].[Zip] = [sZipCode]
        ,(
            SELECT gZipPoint
            FROM [Zip] WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE sZipCode = '30301'
        ) AS qryOrigin  
    WHERE 
        NULLIF([ActiveApp], '') IS NOT NULL
        AND NULLIF([ActiveScheduling], '') IS NOT NULL
        AND NULLIF([Adult], '') IS NOT NULL
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to all that have provided info/comments. It's clear that this query is using SQL-89 join syntax, which is why I've never seen it before. :P However, the query *also* uses modern joins, which makes it even weirder. I cut a lot of this out for the sake of brevity, but I'm adding one join back in, because now I'm unsure what to use for the `ON` condition when I replace the SQL-89 join. See the updated query code.

Comment: This looks like a time-travelling query from the days prior to the ansi-92 sql standard. Confusing, and why the modern join syntax was adopted (30 years ago).

Comment: For one thing it's using SQL-89 syntax which was superseded by SQL-92 syntax.  My calendar says that it is 2021 which makes this code obsolete by almost 30 years.

Comment: Some links to get you started in renovating this antique. Don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Don't splatter your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    [Address] AS [Address]
FROM 
    [AgencySitesV3] WITH (NOLOCK)
    ,(
        SELECT gZipPoint
        FROM [Zip] WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE sZipCode = '30301'
        ) AS qryOrigin  -- this is the table alias for 
        -- the derived table from the sub query
WHERE 
    NULLIF([ActiveApp], '') IS NOT NULL
    AND NULLIF([ActiveScheduling], '') IS NOT NULL
    AND NULLIF([Adult], '') IS NOT NULL
```

This query is using old styled joins to get a cartesan product from the addresss column with the derived table's output. Meaning it is getting all combinations of the two outputs. It should be a CROSS JOIN, but whatever.

Simply put - it is getting all addresses for zip code 30301

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Doug! I'm trying to replace this old SQL-89 syntax now, but I'm unsure what `ON` condition to use in the new join. I'd appreciate another look at the Edit in my question.

Comment: @rabadash8820 the cross join syntax doesnt need ON https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php